# 2D Array of RectangleShapes

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, forms, rectangles

I am developing a *very* rudimentary drawing program: A 2D grid comprised of multiple RectangleShapes, around 20x30 pixels each, which when clicked change color based on user RGB input, which works just fine:

```
Color SelectedColor = new Color();
private void Pixel_1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    // on Rectangle click
{
    Pixel_1_1.FillColor = SelectedColor;    // change to currently desired color.
}
```

Since the number of squares is rising dramatically, I'm looking for a way to arrange the "pixel" rectangles into a 2D array. (I really don't want to have to make a Pixel_Click method for every single Rectangle on the screen!) Hoping eventually to be able to call something like:

```
private void Pixel_[x]_[y]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pixel_[x]_[y].FillColor = SelectedColor;
}
```

My friends suggest the use of an anonymous delegate, but I don't understand how to fully use one to solve my problem.

What would be the best way to generate a 2D array of rectangles in a C# Windows Form? And once generated, how can I access them with a single method for variant values of x and y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are probably correct in thinking of each rectangle as an object, it probably isn't correct to think of each rectangle as a windows control, especially since you have so many of them.

So try creating your own rectangle object:

```
public class MyRect {
  public Color FillColor { get; set; }
  public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }

  public MyRect(Rectangle r, Color c) {
    this.Rectangle = r;
    this.FillColor = c;
  }
}
```

Now you just need to keep a list of your objects and paint on a single Panel control (or PictureBox) all of your rectangles:

```
private List<MyRect> myRectangles = new List<MyRect>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  myRectangles.Add(new MyRect(new Rectangle(10, 10, 64, 16), Color.Blue));
  myRectangles.Add(new MyRect(new Rectangle(20, 48, 16, 64), Color.Red));
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  foreach (MyRect mr in myRectangles) {
    using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(mr.FillColor)) {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, mr.Rectangle);
    }
  }
}
```

To handle the "click" event of the rectangles, you just handle the `MouseDown` or `MouseClick` event of your container control and determine yourself which rectangle is being clicked on:

```
void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    foreach (MyRect mr in myRectangles) {
      if (mr.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location)) {
        ChangeColor(mr, Color.Green);
      }
    }
    panel1.Invalidate();
  }
}

private void ChangeColor(MyRect mr, Color newColor) {
  mr.FillColor = newColor;
}
```

Comment: @Doc Correct.  The default rectangle class has several different constructor parameters, but I chose x, y, width and height to create my sample rectangles.

Comment: This worked rather well, thank you! - The rectangles draw as intended in the panel.  I can't seem to get the click event to recognize, however.  According to debug, it never detects a click on any part of the panel.

Comment: @Doc Make sure the event is being handled.  From the designer, click on the panel, then in the property window, click on the lightning bolt to see the list of events for that control.  Double-click on an event to have the designer auto-wire it for you.  Otherwise, you would have to do it in code (after `InitializeComponent();`: `panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDown);`

Comment: Perfect, I believe that's everything!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Doc `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(...)`  It uses a pen instead of a brush.  You might have to resize the rectangle by substracting a pixel from the width and height to draw the border correctly.  Goofy Microsoft *feature*.  Draw the border *after* you fill the rectangle.

Comment: Okay, one last question:  I'm intending to use 2 nested loop statements to traverse the entire grid, and return a string with a number based on the FillColor in each Rectangle.  Is there some way I can have my code look at each square in order?  Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @Doc I think you are venturing into new question territory, because I don't know enough about your code to answer that.  I don't know the relationship between these rectangles and the grid.  You can always add a Point variable to the MyRect class and that point would represent the x and y of the grid, then when you loop, you match the x'x and y's.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the rectangles as components on screen then you can assign all of them the same click event, the click event will have a little dropdown to pick an existing event. To know which recantangle was clicked use the `sender` parameter `((Pixel)sender).FillColor = SelectedColor;`

For ease I would recommend using something like a panel and drawing rectangles on it, That means you only have a single click event to deal with. So now your question becomes "How do I draw a grid of rectangles on a panel" and "How do I know which rectangle was clicked"

So for the first part you could use this not the very efficient way.

Create a class which stores the information about your pixels

```
class MyPixel
{
    public Color PixelColour;
    public Rectangle Bounds;
}
```

Keep a list of them in memory

```
List<MyPixels> MyGrid = new List<MyPixels>();
```

then in the onpaint event of the panel Draw the pixels on the panel

```
foreach(MyPixel Pixel in MyGrid)
{
    using(Brush B = new SolidBrush(Pixel.PixelColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(B, Pixel.Bounds);
    }
}
```

Now in the click event you'll need to know which pixel was clicked

```
foreach(MyPixel Pixel in MyGrid)
{
    if (Pixel.Bounds.Contains(e.Location))
    {
        PixelClicked(Pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work.  As green as I am, it'll be a while until I know for sure, but I will do my best.

So this final piece of code you gave is in the Click Event of the panel itself?

Comment: @Doc yes, it's actually very similar to Lars answer (although that is more complete). As you increase the number of pixels you may want to improve the hit testing (the click event) to calculate the correct pixel instead of looping through.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm - Would you also know how to go about changing every "pixel" at once?  For example, if I were to reset them all to the same, default color?  I've attempted unsuccessfully with:
`foreach (MyRect pixel in myRectangles)
{
pixel.FillColor = Color.Black;
}`

Comment: @Doc, That should work but you probably need to invalidate the panel, there's no connection between changing a pixels colour and windows requirement to draw it on screen. Just after your `foreach` loop call `panel.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going about this the wrong way. What you want to do is to draw directly into a bitmap. Here is some code that uses a PictureBox to allow the user to draw into it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private Pen _pen;

            private bool _mouseDown;
            private int _startX;
            private int _startY;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                _pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            }

            private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                _mouseDown = true;

                _startX = e.X;
                _startY = e.Y;
            }

            private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                _mouseDown = false;
            }

            private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (_mouseDown)
                {
                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
                    {
                        graphics.DrawLine(_pen, _startX, _startY, e.X, e.Y);
                        _startX = e.X;
                        _startY = e.Y;
                    }
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the normal method to write a painting app and is quite performant as well. You can also easily save, write new tools or manipulate images better in this way.

Comment: I see why you'd think that, but the program isn't actually working with single pixels.  The Rectangles are currently 20 by 30 pixels.  (The program itself exports a string of ASCII art.)

Comment: Ah, I see that your purpose is different. I thought you wanted a painting app when you mentioned MS Paint. I'll leave this here in case someone else who wants a painting app comes along.

Comment: I just now realized how my use of the word "pixel" was misleading.  But that is some pretty snazzy code you posted nonetheless.